# Converting index to datetime results in strange error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Im trying to pull in some stock data from the alphavantage API.

I turn the json returned into a dictionary and select the appropriate sub dictionary (whose key is 'Time Series (Daily)'. This returns a dictionary whose keys are the timestamps and values are the stock prices.

When I convert this dictionary into a Dataframe, it works fine. The dataframe can be printed as such no problem.

But when I try to convert the index to a datetime, printing the dataframe throws the error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-fc4c9d01b0d9> in <module>
     13     r = requests.get(stock_api+symbol+st_apikey)
     14     seriesjson= json.loads(r.text)
---> 15     datadict=seriesjson['Time Series (Daily)']
     16     df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datadict,orient='index')
     17     df=df[['4. close']]

KeyError: 'Time Series (Daily)'
```

Here is the full code

```
stock_api = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol='
st_apikey='&apikey=SW0SNXDURLOZJJ55'

symbols = {
    'Dow Jones':'DJI',
    'SPDR Crude':'XOP',
    'USO':'USO'
}

stock_dfs=[df_eia]

for name,symbol in symbols.items():
    r = requests.get(stock_api+symbol+st_apikey)
    seriesjson= json.loads(r.text)
    datadict=seriesjson['Time Series (Daily)']
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datadict,orient='index')
    df=df[['4. close']]
    df.columns=[symbol+'_Closing']

    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

    stock_dfs.append(df)


print(df)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says `KeyError: 'Time Series (Daily)'`. So "Time Series (Daily)" is not one of the dictionary keys.

seriesjson is a Dictionary. Try checking whether 'Time Series (Daily)' is in 
`seriesjson.keys()`.

Comment: I did. It definitely was. I inspected the dictionary closely. And the thing is, sometimes seriesjson was pulling in the data just fine, but when i tried to merge it with another dataframe thats when it threw that error. But yeah somehow restarting the notebook seemed to work

Answer (score 0):

Huh. I restarted the Jupyter notebook and now its working.

Oh well